# Why does my Outlook becomes slow and sometimes unresponsive after starting an app to clear the clipboard?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had a requirement to disable Copy Paste and even the print screen key while a website is running. So I wrote a WPF application to keep clearing the clipboard when Open Website link is clicked and stop clearing as soon as Close website button. But the problem is that when I press Open Website button the outlook client becomes very slow and sometimes unresponsive. I know that it has something to do with the clipboard only. Is there a way to disable Outlooks clipboard until the button is pressed.

However the code is not required but is included bleow, or can be [downloaded from Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/onvkca4xc21hwi6/New%20Text%20Document%20%282%29.txt):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
namespace ccb
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string docNum,qs;
        int status = 0;
        static string connectionstring = "SERVER=abcd.com;port=3306;DATABASE=abcd_secure;UID=abcd_sec;PASSWORD=abcd_sec";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);
        private static Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private string RandomString(int size)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            char ch;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
                builder.Append(ch);
            }
            return builder.ToString();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            status = 1;
            Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(clear);
            backgroundThread.IsBackground = true;
            backgroundThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            backgroundThread.Start();
            qs=generaterandomnumber();
            insert(qs);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://abcd/login.php?osid=win&id="+qs);

        }
        private void clear()
        {
            while (status == 1)
                System.Windows.Clipboard.Clear();
        }
        //Genrate random number and encrypt it to MD5
        private string generaterandomnumber()
        {
            string Rand1 = RandomString(8);
            string Rand2 = RandomString(8);
            docNum = Rand1 + "-" + Rand2;
            MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(docNum));
            //get hash result after compute it
            byte[] result = md5.Hash;
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                //change it into 2 hexadecimal digits
                //for each byte
                strBuilder.Append(result[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            return strBuilder.ToString();
        }
        //Insert the generated value to the database
        protected void insert(string q)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                string ins = "insert into mgen_validation_check(md5values) values(@m)";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(ins, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", q);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://abcd/include/LogoutPage.php");
            this.Close();
            status = 0;
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                string del = "delete from mgen_validation_check where md5values=@m";
                MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(del, conn);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", qs);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://abcd/include/LogoutPage.php");
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                string delconf = "delete from mgen_validation_check where md5values=@m";
                MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand(delconf, conn);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", docNum);
                cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The app is working properly except when running outlook becomes very slow. Other ms office apps are working properly.

Any help would be helpful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This really does sound like you're asking for help with the wrong problem. The clipboard is built deeply into the OS and attempts to "disable" it are probably doomed to fail. What **problem** were you trying to solve where you decided that the **solution** required you to "disable" the clipboard?

Comment: When outlook was getting slow I thought the problem may be related to the clipboard itself.

Comment: I agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Sounds like you are trying to prevent copy-pasting from the website ... users could CTRL+S and save the page, circumventing all this. Or right-click -> view source. Or use the Windows Snipping Tool. Or snap it with the OneNote tool. Or copy the url in another window to load the website without obstacles. Or use a webproxy (this is probably unlikely). Or they could print the page.

Comment: There is a [known Clipboard.Clear()](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/038ee435-4631-4cc4-b429-e9d28d3bb309/clipboardclear-plus-a-right-click-on-the-desktop-causes-crashes-in-explorerexe-and-mmcexe?forum=w7itproperf) bug that cause a heap corruption.
A workaround consists in doing Clipboard.SetText("");